# Frame rate reduction using Android and Opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv

How can I reduce the frame rate in an android device?, I'm using setPreviewFpsRange. I need to process images in less than one second therfore I need to read at 5fps. I am using android and opencv.

Comment: The method you specify implies a range of fps perhaps? Have you seen the `VideoCapture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 5);` capability of OpenCV?

Comment: I`m getting the camera parameters and set new params and set into the camera                                                                                         Parameters parameters;
       
        parameters=camara.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(ancho, alto);

        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(1);
        parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(5000,30000);

Comment: ok, so you are getting the parameters as a local variable with the first get - setting all the various values, but you are not setting the parameters again on the camera object? You need to give the camera the new values with setParameters if there is something like that.

Comment: Ops, I forget send the others lines, but I actually sending to the camera with this lines  formatoImagen=parameters.getPreviewFormat();
        camara.setParameters(parameters);
        camara.startPreview(), my problem is that i want some time to process the preview image that I obtain, that is the objective that I am trying to reduce the frame rate

Comment: Perhaps you should try a different approach - limit your image capturing by the speed of your image processing. If the speed of processing is faster than one second, you sleep for a time if possible, otherwise you only capture an image when you are done processing. This will allow you to develop the app for a wide range of device capabilities. Let the application limit the rate of processing, not the device capabilities.